# React with ASP.NET Core - publishing with http 404 error

Tags: reactjs, azure, asp.net-core

Using Visual Studio 2022 React with .NET Core template. It has 2 separate projects: the project has been published to Azure, but it returns a http 404 "page not found" error.

In local debug mode, I usually run the react project with `npm start` and opens in `localhost:3000`. And if I simply run the project, it just opens the API (json data).

I am wondering how to make the react page open on the deployed site? Is the client project even published? As Microsoft suggested, I have added client project as project reference to the server project. But I don't know how this thing works.

[image]

Here is Git: https://github.com/navjotnabha/OnBo2023

Here is the Azure link : https://onbo2023server20231229100652.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: After following your steps to create a default project release, everything works fine, and your repo link is no longer accessible.

Comment: @Yugraaj Sandhu using your [git](https://github.com/navjotnabha/OnBoarding2k23) . everything works well after deployment to Azure. Tested with `Linux` and `Windows` on azure

Answer (score 0):

Using your [git](https://github.com/navjotnabha/OnBoarding2k23), everything works well after deployment to Azure. It has been tested with `Linux` and `Windows` on Azure.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Home extends Component {
  static displayName = Home.name;

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <p>Welcome to your new single-page application, built with:</p>
        <ul>
          <li><a href='https://get.asp.net/'>ASP.NET Core</a> and <a href='https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx'>C#</a> for cross-platform server-side code</li>
          <li><a href='https://facebook.github.io/react/'>React</a> for client-side code</li>
          <li><a href='http://getbootstrap.com/'>Bootstrap</a> for layout and styling</li>
        </ul>
        <p>To help you get started, we have also set up:</p>
        <ul>
          <li><strong>Client-side navigation</strong>. For example, click <em>Counter</em> then <em>Back</em> to return here.</li>
          <li><strong>Development server integration</strong>. In development mode, the development server from <code>create-react-app</code> runs in the background automatically, so your client-side resources are dynamically built on demand and the page refreshes when you modify any file.</li>
          <li><strong>Efficient production builds</strong>. In production mode, development-time features are disabled, and your <code>dotnet publish</code> configuration produces minified, efficiently bundled JavaScript files.</li>
        </ul>
        <p>The <code>ClientApp</code> subdirectory is a standard React application based on the <code>create-react-app</code> template. If you open a command prompt in that directory, you can run <code>npm</code> commands such as <code>npm test</code> or <code>npm install</code>.</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Azure:**

[image]

The code below includes models for a store, sale, product, and customer, representing entities in a database schema. Code taken from [git](https://github.com/navjotnabha/onboardingProject/tree/master).

```cs
 [ApiController]
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
 public class CustomerController : ControllerBase
 {
     private readonly NavbaseContext _db;

     public CustomerController(NavbaseContext db)
     {
         _db = db ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(db));
     }

     [HttpGet]
     [Route("GetCustomers")]
     public IActionResult GetCustomers()
     {
         List<Customer> customerList = _db.Customers.ToList();
         return Ok(customerList);
     }

     [HttpPost]
     public IActionResult Add(Customer c)
     {
         _db.Customers.Add(c);
         _db.SaveChanges();
         return RedirectToAction("GetCustomers");
     }

     [HttpDelete]
     [Route("DeleteCustomer")]
     public IActionResult DeleteCustomer(int? id)
     {
         Customer existingCustomer = _db.Customers.FirstOrDefault(temp => temp.Id == id);

         if (existingCustomer != null)
         {
             _db.Customers.Remove(existingCustomer);
             _db.SaveChanges();
         }

         return RedirectToAction("GetCustomers");
     }
 }
```

**Azure:**

[image]

[image]